# BlazeDS Channel connects and disconnects immediately

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds, amf

I am connecting to a BlazeDS server with a simple Flex component that is merely trying to subscribe to realtime data

Here are the Channels and Consumer

```
    <mx:ChannelSet id="channelSet">
            <mx:AMFChannel url="http://localhost:8080/MyApp/messagebroker/streamingamf/"/>     
    </mx:ChannelSet>        
    <mx:Consumer id="consumer" 
                 destination="feed" 
                 channelSet="{channelSet}"
                 channelConnect="consumer_channelConnectHandler(event)"
                 channelDisconnect="consumer_channelDisconnectHandler(event)"
                 message="consumer_messageHandler(event.message)"
                 fault="consumer_faultHandler(event)"/>
```

I am being disconnected right after connecting (both consumer_channelConnectHandler and consumer_channelDisconnectHandler are invoked).

Would you have a clue why?

Comment: Kinda hard to debug this without a log of what's going on.  My hunch is that either the destination is not properly set on the server or the server is not authorizing the channel.

Comment: Thanks! I had to switch the log level to "All" to see something in the console. Which pointed me in th eright direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of things to note here:

- You have a StreamingAMF endpoint configured to an AMFChannel.  This is wrong, I suspect you want a `StreamingAMFChannel`.
- If you're using an `AMFChannel` with a consumer, you need to talk to an `AMFLongPolling` endpoint, in which case your `AMFChannel` should have `pollingEnabled` set to true.  however, I suspect you really want `StreamingAMFChannel`, in which case, see point 1.
- Once you configure `StreamingAMFChannel`, you can find that you still get immediate disconnections on the client.  This occurs when you have multiple connections from the same client (ie., tabs), and your `services-config.xml` has a `max-streaming-connections-per-session` set too low.  Normally you would want this set to 1, but for development, that can be painful, so set it higher, and use a seperate `services-config.xml` with production settings for production.

Comment: Thanks for catching this. I changed the channel type as per your suggestion.